# make install make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop

Tags: installation

make install
iam getting this issue below
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

how to solve this ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the answer to the question is, that the Makefile has no rules for installing the built software. In other words, all of the products produced by make are contained in the directory (or subdirectories) where the make was performed. So for example there is probably an executable that can be run by doing a ./executable.